# Execution order of actions

Tags: smart-contract, action

I want to implement "continious minting" which means first I should call `issue`, and only then `transfer`.

My contract has a functionality of eosio.token . I call `create` to create my token with max_supply and supply=0.0000 . Under certain circumstances I should call `issue`, then `transfer` to fund some account. I would prefer to include these actions into one transaction.
I wonder is there any guarantee on the order of execution of actions inside one transaction.

OR, I can create new action which will call these two actions inside: two inline actions. But, still I don't know, is there a guarantee on inline action execution?

Comment: there's guarantee for the order of inline action execution, but not transaction

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a guarantee on the order of actions within a transaction. So you can either create two inline actions that you call from a single action. Or you can create a transaction with the two actions in the correct order and push that transaction to chain.